# converting from node-sass to sass - alternative to using a parent selector in a mixin

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vite, node-sass

I am trying to upgrade my `Vue` stack to support `vite` because it generates a much faster codebase for use on the web. I have done this in several projects, but not on any that use `sass`. Since `vite` uses `sass` instead of `node-sass`, I have to migrate all my sass code as well. I am using a sass-heavy 3rd-party element toolkit and it is throwing the following error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Top-level selectors may not contain the parent selector "&".
   ╷
71 │     &.el-select-dropdown.is-multiple
   │     ^
   ╵
```

the block says:

```
@mixin select($type, $color) {
  .select-#{$type}.el-select .el-input  {
    .el-input__suffix{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
  /* more code goes here */
  &.el-select-dropdown.is-multiple
  .el-select-dropdown__item.selected{
    &.select-#{$type}{
      color: $color;
    }
  }
}

@include select('default', $default-color);
@include select('info', $info-color);
```

How would I refactor this to be compatible with the sass standard? Or, why/how is this working with node-sass?

Comment: There is no refactoring needed as I can tell. Your issue is exactly that `Top-level selectors may not contain the parent selector "&"`. This mixin has to be used in a selector, like `.foo { @include select('default', $color) }.`

Comment: @AmauryHanser sorry, but i am a little confused. You are saying it doesn't need to be refactored (restructured without changing its behavior), but you appear to be giving an example of its refactoring.

Comment: @AmauryHanser thank you! i think i understand a little now. I just need to remove the `&` because it was nto actually doing anything.

Comment: I'll write an answer, it would be easier to understand with a proper formating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's have a look at the mixin:**

```
@mixin select($type, $color) {
  .select-#{$type}.el-select .el-input  {
    .el-input__suffix{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
  /* more code goes here */
  &.el-select-dropdown.is-multiple
  .el-select-dropdown__item.selected{
    &.select-#{$type}{
      color: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

**It's made of two blocks**

### First block:

```
  .select-#{$type}.el-select .el-input  {
    .el-input__suffix{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
```

This one is easy, when you do `@include select('default', $default-color);` it will simply define the selector as: `.select-default.el-select .el-input`:

```
.select-default.el-select .el-input  {
    .el-input__suffix{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
}
```

It will compile to:

```
.select-default.el-select .el-input .el-input__suffix {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

### Second block:

```
  &.el-select-dropdown.is-multiple
  .el-select-dropdown__item.selected{
    &.select-#{$type}{
      color: $color;
    }
  }
```

It's using the `&`, this is the **parent selector** in sass:

> The parent selector, &, is a special selector invented by Sass that’s used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector. It makes it possible to re-use the outer selector in more complex ways, like adding a pseudo-class or adding a selector before the parent.
> [Parent Selector - Sass lang](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

It will be replaced by the parent selector, **if you are trying to use the mixin at the root level, you don't have a parent selector, that's why it's failing**.

If you use it within a selector (parent selector):

```
.foobar {
  @include select('default', $default-color);
}
```

The `&` will be replaced by `.foobar`.

```
  .foobar.el-select-dropdown.is-multiple
  .el-select-dropdown__item.selected{
    &.select-default{
      color: $default-color;
    }
  }
```

### Conclusion

The mixin is perfectly fine, you just need to use it ***inside*** a parent selector.